# Grab HTML of Element and Remove Style Tag of It's Children

Tags: jquery

Fiddle - http://codepen.io/mikethedj4/pen/BCJun

[image]

I've been working on a website designer for my tablet and it's almost ready for release, but I have one problem.

You see while I'm adjusting the style properties to get a nice visual style by default the browser adds those css modifications of the element to a style attribute. Which I'm sure most of you are aware of.

I'm trying to only show the children of the `div.canves` elements, without the style tag, but without having it affect the view of `div.canves`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by mirroring the `.canves` html to a separate div's html and removing the styles in there. This way it doesn't remove the styles inside of the elements of `.canves` which is working perfectly for me.

```
$(".open-save-dialog").on('click', function() {
  $(".yourhtml").html($(".canves").html());
  $(".yourhtml *").removeAttr('style');
  $(".html-sheet").val($(".yourhtml").html().replace(/>/g,'>\n    ').replace(/</g,'\n  <'));
  $('.mirror-title').text( $('.website-title').val() );
  $(".mirror-css").text( $('.css-sheet').val() );
  $(".mirror-html").text( $(".html-sheet").val() );
  $('#code').val( $('.mirror-code').text() );
  saveTextAsHTML();
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

$(".html-sheet").val($(".canves").children().clone().removeAttr('style'));

Comment: I updated the question as I solved the html problem. `$(".yourhtml").html($(".canves").html()); $(".yourhtml *").removeAttr('style'); $(".html-sheet").val($(".yourhtml").html());`

Comment: i'm not sure if it's correct to change the question while i've already posted working answer, you should close that one and create a new question, possibly inviting someone (like me) to participate in a new topic via a link

Comment: I posted the new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22573689/get-html-styles-from-children-and-show-in-textarea